# How to Unsubscribe from Firestore listener

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm listening to the Firestore database, even though I unsubscribed to the observable on component destroy, it doesn't unsubscribe from the Firebase service.

following is the service that listens to Firebase collection

```
getVehiclesLiveLocations(orgId: string) {
  return this.firestore
  .collection(orgId)
  .doc('VEHICLES')
  .collection('LOCATION_CHANGES')
    .snapshotChanges();
}
```

following is the function that subscribe to the above service

```
this.firebaseService.getVehiclesLiveLocations(orgId)
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
      mergeMap(data => {
        return from(data
          .map((e): VehicleLiveLocation[] => {
          const document = e.payload.doc.data();
          return (document.latestCoordinates || [])
            .map(position => {
              return {
                jobRefId: document[`jobRefId`],
                containerId: document[`containerId`],
                vehicleRegNo: document[`vehicleRegNumber`],
                position: {lat: position.latitude, lng: position.longitude},
                incident: document[`incident`] ?? false,
                warning: document[`warning`] ?? false,
                checkedIn: document[`checkedIn`],
                offline: document[`offline`],
                vehicleId: document[`vehicleId`],
                jpmId: document[`jpmId`],
                heading: position?.heading,
                updatedAt: document[`createdAt`].toDate(),
                status: document[`status`],
                finishingStatus: document[`finishingStatus`] ?? ''
              };
            });
          }).filter((locations: VehicleLiveLocation[]) => locations)
        );
      }).subscribe()
```

as you can see this observable is unsubscribed on component `destroy()`. but it still emits values.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two different databases. While both are part of Firebase and support listening for live updates, they are completely separate from each other. To prevent confusion, take care to use the correct name and tag for the database that you're actually using and asking about.